# MigraDoc Images in a Paragraph - not Full File Path

Tags: c#, image, migradoc

I want to display an image within a paragraph in MigraDoc. So far, the examples I have found have all required the full file path to reference the image file:

```
answerParagraph.AddImage("C:\Project\Images\Image.png")
```

However I want to use some kind of relative path or namespace reference. Or even an actual Image Object. Anything but the full file path.

Comment: Your code snippet will work better with @ before the string.`@"C:\Project\Images\Image.png"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF renderer allows to set a working directory (property `WorkingDirectory` in class `PdfDocumentRenderer`). I think the same applies to the RTF renderer.

Searches for files with relative path will start from this working directory.

The samples you can download for MigraDoc all use relative paths. One example:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/HelloMigraDoc-sample.ashx

```
Image image = section.AddImage("../../images/Logo landscape.png");
```

I don't know which samples you looked at - but requiring absolute paths would not be comfortable for sample code that should compile and work anywhere the user unzips it.

You can also pass the binary data of the image in a pseudo-filename (PDF renderer only). See also:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDoc_FilelessImages.ashx

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should correct myself there, they were relative paths I was finding, I was only half thinking when I typed it out (that's a lesson). I didnt get much luck with the relative paths and had since found the same article on the pseudo-filename stream method. I have given that a go but am still getting 'Image Not Found' (or similar) on render. The images are getting picked up and a vLID

Comment: ... valid base64 filename created... Alas my debugging goes on!

Comment: Make sure you are using PDFsharp/MigraDoc 1.50 (not 1.32 or older).

Comment: I will check later but I got it from NuGet a couple of days ago so imagine it is the latest version. If I get stuck I will create a new Question with example code. I am passing the pseudo-filename between classes but that is the only difference really. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Yup - Turns out NuGet is only currently throwing out version 1.32 so that is probably going to be my problem. Will look into getting the latest version.

Comment: Probably because 1.5 is Beta... Not sure how that affects our licensing requirements but will look into it.